# How to get string input from STDIN and save it in a variable in bash to use it on other parts of the script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a script that will create a new user on a linux (ubuntu) server. I'm new to script writing, I'm having problems on

how to read variables from the user input and using that variable in other parts of the script

This is sort of what I have, but getting stuck in the execution of it. Thanks.

```sh
update_pkgs() {
  echo "
----------------------
  Prerequisites : Making sure everything is up to date
----------------------
"
  # checks is all pkgs are up to date
  sudo apt-get update -y

  # installing necessary pkgs
  sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev -y
}

create_user() {
  echo "
----------------------
  1. Creating a new user with name `<user>` and gives correct access.
----------------------
"
 # [ASK]: How to make <user> a variable I read from STDIN
 #        and  pass it around in the following commands

  # add new user with the name of `user`
  sudo adduser --ingroup www-data --disabled-password <user>


  # copy ssh/ folder from `ubuntu` user to new user 
  # and gives the right permissions/privileges 
  sudo cp -R .ssh/ /home/<user>/
  sudo chown -R <user>:www-data /home/<user>/.ssh/  
}


# 1. asks to run the script

echo "
----------------------
  Do You Wish to run this Script ?
----------------------
"

select yn in "Yes" "No" create quit; do
    case $yn in
        Yes) 
          update_pkgs();
          create_user(); 
          break;;
        No) exit;;
        create)
        read -p "Enter name of user: " user
        create_user($user)
        quit)
          break;;
        *) 
          echo 'Invalid option $REPLY'
    esac
done
```

Comment: Since you have two unrelated problems, please ask two questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` always runs commands in order, unless you tell it to run the command in the background.

You can see how to save the stdin to a variable [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/365222/189554).

Comment: @dozeman so if I understand you correctly `create_user()` will run and only after `update_pkgs();` is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You should make the question more focused. As regards the request in the title (*How to get input from STDIN and save it in a variable in bash*), it is too generic too.

The answer depends on what you expect to be given from stdin (One word? One line? More lines?), what do you plan to do with it (read in a "scalar" variable, or in an array?), and other factors.

For instance, executing the following in the terminal is enough to read a line from stdin to a a variable named `var`:

```sh
read var
```

But you want something more for sure.

Comment: just updated the question for clarity. Thanks.